# Bootstrap CSS issues in different browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For an unknown reason the Twitter bootsrap is displaying the scroll arrow buttons not the way it should be. Is this a known issue or something is wrong with my browsers? I have tested in different ones: Firefox 24.0 (windows os), and Chrome 31.0.1650.57 (windows os). The only one working is Chrome 22.0.1229.94 (ubuntu).

Any help is welcome.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: How are you expecting them to show?  Are you referencing the difference between the two?  That's the difference between `select` and `select multiple`.

Comment: @SethMcClaine It's the last version of bootstrap. The image is in fact a view of bootstrap official docs.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson Is the Twitter bootstrap official page.

Comment: How is it appearing in your instance?  Add your HTML and CSS, please.

Comment: CSS and HTML are the ones of the official bootstrap docs webpage.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson Chrome OS for windows (v.31.0.1650.57) is throwing this warnings: [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=nr9z7pWS)